# Are my two nomograms build with different packages in R (HDnom vs Dynnom) identical?

Tags: r, prediction, modeling, cox-regression

I have question concerning nomograms and cox regression models, for which i desparetely need help!

I build a predictive nomogram using the aenet function of the HDnom package in R (fod high dimensial cox models). I validated and calibrated the model and i am satisfied with the results.

This is my code for the HDnom nomogram:

```
library(hdnom)         
d <- read_xlsx("Nomo.xlsx", sheet = "Training")        
d <- d        
x <- model.matrix( ~  x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, d)    
time <- d$Time_to_recurrence    
event <- d$Recurrence     
y <- Surv(d$Time_to_recurrence, d$Recurrence)     

suppressMessages(library("rms"))    
x.df =as.data.frame(x)     
dd =datadist(x.df)     
options(datadist = "dd")       
fit <- fit_aenet(x, y, nfolds = 10, rule = "lambda.1se", seed = c(5, 7), parallel = TRUE)     
names(fit)      
model <- fit$model     
alpha <- fit$alpha     
lambda <- fit$lambda      
adapen <- fit$pen_factor      
nom <- as_nomogram(fit, x, time, event, pred.at = 12 * 2, funlabel = "2-Year Recurrence-Free  Survival Probability")       
plot(nom)      
print(nom)
```

This nomogram now includes the following factor: x1, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9

Now, i found the Dynnom package, which allows you to upload a dynamic version of your nomogram (based on cox models) online (which is pretty userfriendly and cool).

This is my code for the DynNom nomogram (in the coxmodel, i included the same factors from the HDnom nomogram) :

```
library(rsconnect)
library(DynNom)
library(rsconnect)
Coxmodel <- coxph(Surv(Time_to_recurrence, Recurrence) ~ x1, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9 , d)       
summary(Coxmodel)        
DynNom(Coxmodel, d)        
Dynnom <- DynNom(Coxmodel, d, ptype = "1-st")                  
DNbuilder(Dynnom, data = NULL, clevel = 0.95, m.summary = c("raw"), covariate = c("slider", "numeric"), ptype = c("st"), DNtitle = "Preoperative Prediction Of Recurrence-Free Survival", DNxlab = NULL, DNylab = NULL, DNlimits = NULL, KMtitle = NULL, KMxlab = NULL, KMylab = NULL)             
rsconnect::deployApp('Userinfo')
```

**Now my question is pretty simple: are my two nomograms identical?** How can I test that?
In my understanding, as the variables used (x1, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9)      there should be no difference, correct?

I really appreciate any help! I've been reading up on this for days but its so hard to find reliable informations... Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem with this question is in the line with `read_xlsx("Nomo.xlsx", sheet = "Training") `. SO requires a [MCVE] for debugging or demonstrations on specific dataset. So if this question could be modified to use an easily avaialble dataset, say one of the examples in one of the packages that are standard (e.g. pkg:survival) or in your less widely used packages, then your question would fit the SO requirements.

Comment: I took a look at the documentation for `fit_aenet`. It seems very unlikely that the models it creates would be the same as the models you get from `coxph`, since `fit_aenet` penalizes its coefficients. I'm not sure why pkg:`rms` was loaded and datadist used. I don't see that the nomogram facilities of that package were used.